# In django how to move objects from a sessions foreign key to a user foreign key when the user logs in

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a model that saves a endusers progress on a task.

```
class TaskCompleted(models.Model):
   session = models.ForeignKey('sessions.Session', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
   task = models.ForeignKey(Task, blank=True, null=True)
```

The enduser might be logged in or might not be. If they are logged I save the it against the user and if they are not I save it against the session.

When the a user logs in I want to find any tasks they have completed while unauthenticated and then update the user foreign key to relate it to their account.

I am finding that the session is destroyed thus setting the session to Null.

I am interested in other's suggestions on how to handle this?

Comment: Javascript `document.cookie` would do the trick.

Comment: Sorry. Can you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: If the user is unauthenticated, save the completed tasks to a cookie. When the user logs in, pull the tasks from the cookie if it's there and save them related to the user.

Comment: Ok. So you are suggesting that I don't bother trying to save it as a model with a foreign key to a session. ok. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

The session **data** is not destroyed when a user is logged in - the data is saved to a new session (the key is "[cycled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase.cycle_key)").  You can still use `request.session['mykey']`.  You can do a few things to persist/change the ownership of your `TaskCompleted` instance.  One option would be to save the `TaskCompleted` instance id in the session for anonymous users, and override the login view to assign that instance to the user on successful login.  (And if you follow this, you won't need the `session = models.ForeignKey()` field in your model)